# Magento If product price smaller than 100$, set shipping cost to 4$

Tags: javascript, php, html, magento, content-management-system

I have a problem.
I need to know how to make shipping cost 4$ only for products with price smaller than 100$. Price per item not per entire cart.

Thank you

Comment: post example code please.

Comment: I want to do this using a extension. Not editing the code. This is User safe method.

Comment: What shipping method are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/flat-rate-shipping-per-product-1.html
This extension might help you to get atleast specipic shipping rate for specific product.
Check if it is of some help.